# Zero variance gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, reference-request, normal-distribution, dirac-delta

I know that a gaussian distribution will tends to Delta Dirac distribution as the variance goes to zero.
Where can I find a mathematical proof for that conversion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The Dirac delta function has by definition a unit area under its curve and a width (variance) which is zero. So a Gaussian with unit area in the limit of zero variance satisfies both requirements.

Comment: Key words/phrases you can search for here are "convergence in distribution" and "weak convergence". As in, Gaussian "converges in distribution to delta".